# Timestamp of finished Powershell task

Tags: powershell, timestamp, getdate

I have a basic script, which will shutdown Windows services and generate a report about their shutdown processes. I also want to include two more columns into my output variable (`$table`), which will be timestamp values i.e. when shutdown tasks were launched and when they finished. I have no idea how to implement this into my report.

```
$processlist = @('SQLTELEMETRY$TESTDB', 'MSSQL$TESTDB', 'SQLWRITER')
$get = ''
$table = @{ }
$failed = 0


foreach ($proc in $processlist) {
    stop-service -name $proc -force
}

#start-sleep -s 120


foreach ($proc in $processlist) {

    $get = get-service $proc -Erroraction ignore

    if ($get.Status -eq 'Running') {
        $table += @{$proc = 'Running' }
    }
    else {
        $table += @{$proc = 'Stopped' }
    }
}


foreach ($value in $table.GetEnumerator()) {

    if ($value.Value -eq 'Running') {
        $failed += 1
    }
}

if ($failed -gt 0) {
    $err = 'FAILED'
}
else {
    $err = 'SUCCESS'
}

$table.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object -Property Name, Value | export-csv appreport.csv -delimiter ";" -force -notypeinformation

(HTML part here...)
```

Comment: Why don't you think about Start-Transcript cmdlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding stuff into a Hashtable, I think it would be a lot easier to build an array of objects and write that as CSV file.

Something like this:

```
$serviceList = 'SQLTELEMETRY$TESTDB', 'MSSQL$TESTDB', 'SQLWRITER'
$maxAttempts = 10

# $result will become an array of PsCustomObjects you can easily pipe to Export-Csv
$result = foreach ($service in $serviceList) {
    $shutStart = Get-Date
    $svc       = Get-Service -Name $service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($svc) {
        for ($attempt = 0; $attempt -lt $maxAttempts; $attempt++) {
            $shutResult = 'Failed'
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
            $svc | Stop-Service -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            # test if the service has stopped. If so exit the loop
            if (($svc | Get-Service).Status -eq 'Stopped') { 
                $shutResult = 'Success'
                break 
            }
        }
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'ServiceName'        = $svc.Name
            'ServiceDisplayName' = $svc.DisplayName
            'ShutDownStart'      = $shutStart
            'ShutDownEnd'        = Get-Date
            'Result'             = $shutResult
        }
    }
    else {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'ServiceName'        = $service
            'ServiceDisplayName' = ''
            'ShutDownStart'      = $shutStart
            'ShutDownEnd'        = Get-Date
            'Result'             = "Failed: Service '$service' could not be found."
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV
$result | Export-Csv 'D:\appreport.csv' -Delimiter ";" -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

The output on screen will look like this:

> ```
> ServiceName        : SQLTELEMETRY$TESTDB
> ServiceDisplayName : 
> ShutDownStart      : 22-8-2019 16:47:40
> ShutDownEnd        : 22-8-2019 16:47:40
> Result             : Failed: Service 'SQLTELEMETRY$TESTDB' could not be found.
>
> ServiceName        : MSSQL$TESTDB
> ServiceDisplayName : 
> ShutDownStart      : 22-8-2019 16:47:40
> ShutDownEnd        : 22-8-2019 16:47:40
> Result             : Failed: Service 'MSSQL$TESTDB' could not be found.
>
> ServiceName        : SQLWRITER
> ServiceDisplayName : SQL Server VSS Writer
> ShutDownStart      : 22-8-2019 16:47:38
> ShutDownEnd        : 22-8-2019 16:47:39
> Result             : Success
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was expecting! These hashtables and dozens of if's solution was terrible and you improved my code so much, you're so kind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know when you want to capture the time stamp for the services, but I suggest you take advantage of the below property and add it in the loop where you think its suitable.

```
(Get-Process -Name $proc).StartTime
```

Also you can use the below properties :

- UserProcessorTime
- TotalProcessTime
- ExitTime

I hope this will help you to capture to time.